# MS Web Browser on Pocket PC

Tags: c++, mfc, activex, pocketpc

I'm trying to create a custom web browser for on a pocket pc in C++ MFC. When I add the Microsoft Web Browser activeX control and run the app on the pocket pc (emulator) then this error pops up:
"Debug assertion failed. occcont.cpp line: 916"

When I look in the debug window of VS2005:
"CoCreateInstance of OLE control {8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2} failed.
Result code: 0x80040154
Is the control is properly registered?
Warning: Resource items and Win32 Z-order lists are out of sync. Tab order may be not defined well."

How can I use this control on a pocket pc? Or is there a similar control that works?

Comment: So you're trying to make a custom web browser with the M$ web browswer control? <br>I've not seen this control work. But I'll be following the question.. Thanks for it.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I've used this control successfully in .NET CF application. Which means it should work.
I suspect you picked the ActiveX object for the desktop. But I have no idea how you' pick the right one.

Comment: Yes in a C# application it works but the C++ version not.
I was already continuing on the C# application. Thanks for your reply